# "I wasn't expecting" vs."I didn't expect"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Suppose someone drops by and you say **"Hey, I didn't expect to see you today"** or **"Hey, I wasn't expecting to see you today"**.

What is the difference between those two sentences?

To my understanding, the one using **"didn't expect"** refers to a point in the past whereas the one using **"wasn't expecting"** refers to the whole day.

But I find it really hard to understand **when** I should choose one over the other.

Comment: In this context, I don't think there is any difference in meaning between the two tenses. You might also say **I hadn't expected to see you** with the same meaning.